# Loading token in Flask-Login token_loader raises "BadTimeSignature: timestamp missing"

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I want to use Flask-Login's `token_loader` to load the logged in user.  I only want the token to be valid for the value set in the `REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION` config.  When I try to load the token, I get `BadTimeSignature: timestamp missing`.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
@login_manager.token_loader
def load_token(token):
    """This metod is callback, which is used in
    the Login Manager inner logic for retrieving
    data from token.
        :returns User instance or None if token
        is invalid.
    """
    max_age = app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION"].total_seconds()
    data = login_serializer.loads(token, max_age=max_age)

    user = get_user_by_id(data[0])

    if user and data[1] == user.password:
        return user
    return None
```

```
  line 418, in _load_from_cookie
    user = self.token_callback(cookie)
  File "/home/peter/Lv-164.UI/ecomap/src/python/ecomap/user.py", line 127, in load_token
    data = login_serializer.loads(token, max_age = max_age)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 643, in loads
    .unsign(s, max_age, return_timestamp=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 437, in unsign
    raise BadTimeSignature('timestamp missing', payload=result)
BadTimeSignature: timestamp missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you're trying to load was not generated with a `TimedSerializer`, or is otherwise invalid, so it can't find a timestamp to compare against.  Use the correct serializer to generate and load your tokens.  You should also catch these exceptions and log the error since bad data could still be sent.

```
from flask import abort, flash
from itsdangerous import TimedSerializer, BadData, SignatureExpired

# define a timestamp serializer
login_serializer = TimedSerializer(app.secret_key, salt='login')
```

```
# generate the token with the user id (your example assumed a list)
token = login_serializer.dumps([user.id])
```

```
# load the token, but tell the user about expiration and log bad data
try:
    data = login_serializer.loads(token, max_age=max_age)
except SignatureExpired:
    flash('Login token is too old, you need to log in again.')
    abort(401)
except BadData as e:
    app.logger.exception('Bad login token "{}"', token)
    abort(401)
```

---

It is insecure to place the user's password directly in the token, since the token is only signed, not encrypted.  An attacker could see what the user's password hash is and try to crack it.  Instead, either omit the password (since they would only get the token if they successfully logged in with the correct password), or hash it with other information about the user.

```
validation = hash((user.username, user.password))
token = login_serializer.dumps([user.id, validation])

data = login_serializer.loads(token, max_age=max_age)
user = get_user_by_id(data[0])

if hash((user.username, user.password)) != data[1]:
    # did not validate
```